# Check if file is a binary executable

Tags: c

With lstat || stat you can find permission flags for a file (whether you may execute it or not,) but I was wondering if there was a way to determine whether a file is a binary executable or not?

Comment: Any random binary can be executable.

Comment: You should look at the source for the [file](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command.  Code is here: https://github.com/file/file

Comment: Check the [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). For example, if it starts with `0x23 0x21` (`#!`) then it's a script. `0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46` (`.ELF`) marks the start of a Linux executable binary.

Comment: Is a shell script with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the beginning a 'binary' executable for your purposes? Because it acts as an executable.

Comment: Read the first four bytes and see if it matches an [Executable and Linkable Format (ELF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file? And if it does, read the remaining ELF header to see if it's an executable or a library or other kind of ELF file.

Comment: Linux has [binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) for example... so *anything* can be made "executable". If you want to know if a file is an *ELF* executable, you can use elf library to try to read its headers. Of course this requires that the file is *readable* which an executable need *not* be.